# how to add properties files in FLEX4 and AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, properties-file

Is there any existence of properties file in FLEX4/AS3 ? my requirement is to read data from properties file that flex AIR loading time is minimized and should not occupy more memory. my data set is an array containing around 2000 objects in key:value pair format. How can I treat this large data set that it should not occupy more memory and less initial loading time.

Is XML is a better idea ?

Pls provide any suitable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that I understood your question, but using of Vectors (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) could increase the speed of the reading of data. Maybe it will be good to check if it is possible to split the array and use only those parts which you need. Where is this data coming from?